# How to write css classes in php file?

Tags: php, css, dynamic

I am creating some dynamic template and I have an issue that I want to use PHP variables in external CSS file.

**Example:** 
if stylesheet is `styles.css` and then I want to use this file as `styles.php` so that I can use variables in this file to make css dynamic.

What should I do for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

1. Rename file to `styles.php` (or configure server to run PHP interpreter in CSS files).
2. Send appropriate `Content-Type` header:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: text/css');
   ```
3. Write your code:

   ```
   <?php

   header('Content-Type: text/css');

   $a = '#123456';
   $b = '#654321';

   ?>

   body > a {
       color: <?php echo $a ?>;
   }
   ```

Comment: Suspect you'll also want to put some "don't cache me" headers in there as well. (Or perhaps I'm just paranoid.) :-)

Comment: There is any disadvantage to use server configuration instead header and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Use an .htaccess file and the following line:

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .css

This will make your server parse .css files as if they were .php.

Comment: Sounds appropriate but all .css files will be parsed by PHP. If he still uses lots of "legacy" static CSS a slight performance decrease should occur. Anyway +1

Comment: thanks for this but i want to know that what should i use. header() in php file or configuration setting in .htaccess file. Which overcomes the time overheads as well as server level issues if any or page loading issue..

Comment: @djechelon, Yes - that should be taken into consideration.

Comment: A solution I came up with before was to name by static CSS files with a regular .css extension, but the one generated by PHP as *.pcss, then the line in my .htaccess would be AddType application/x-httpd-php .pcss , thus leaving the static CSS files alone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with making dynamically generated CSS files is that they won't be cached. You'll be forcing to user to hit your server at least twice: once for the php output, and once for the css.

If you're only making a few minor parts of the CSS dynamic, consider creating a regular standard CSS file with suitable defaults in it, and then having your PHP pages output a suitable `<style>` block which issues the overrides. That way your main CSS file can be cached, and you get dynamic styles at the cost of a few lines of extra output in your PHP file.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but @MarcB is incorrect on caching

Here is a cachable version of the php CSS

```
<?php
  ob_start ("ob_gzhandler");
  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
  $offset = 60 * 60 ;
  $ExpStr = "Expires: " .
  gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",
  time() + $offset) . " GMT";
  header($ExpStr);
  $blue="#00f";
  $red="#f00";
  $green="#0f0";
 ?>
  #div{
   color:<?=$blue?>;
   background:<?=$red?>
 }
```